# Sidebar menu on Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogs, blogger, side-menu

I'm working on blogger by building a web page for job seekers.

However, when I added the sidebar menu, it came up a problem.

Any ideas how to fix the code?

https://rabotav4ujbina.blogspot.bg

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function showlatestpostswiththumbs(t){document.write('<ul class="recent-posts-container">');for(var e=0;e<posts_no;e++){var r,n=t.feed.entry[e],i=n.title.$t;if(e==t.feed.entry.length)break;for(var o=0;o<n.link.length;o++){if("replies"==n.link[o].rel&&"text/html"==n.link[o].type)var l=n.link[o].title,m=n.link[o].href;if("alternate"==n.link[o].rel){r=n.link[o].href;break}}var u;try{u=n.media$thumbnail.url}catch(h){s=n.content.$t,a=s.indexOf("<img"),b=s.indexOf('src="',a),c=s.indexOf('"',b+5),d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5),u=-1!=a&&-1!=b&&-1!=c&&""!=d?d:"https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C3Mo0iKKiSw/VGdK808U7rI/AAAAAAAAAmI/W7Ae_dsEVAE/s1600/no-thumb.png"}var p=n.published.$t,f=p.substring(0,4),g=p.substring(5,7),v=p.substring(8,10),w=new Array;if(w[1]="Jan",w[2]="Feb",w[3]="Mar",w[4]="Apr",w[5]="May",w[6]="Jun",w[7]="Jul",w[8]="Aug",w[9]="Sep",w[10]="Oct",w[11]="Nov",w[12]="Dec",document.write('<li class="recent-posts-list">'),1==showpoststhumbs&&document.write('<a href="'+r+'"><img class="recent-post-thumb" src="'+u+'"/></a>'),document.write('<div class="recent-post-title"><a href="'+r+'" target ="_top">'+i+"</a></div>"),"content"in n)var A=n.content.$t;else if("summary"in n)var A=n.summary.$t;else var A="";var k=/<\S[^>]*>/g;if(A=A.replace(k,""),1==post_summary)if(A.length<summary_chars)document.write(A);else{A=A.substring(0,summary_chars);var y=A.lastIndexOf(" ");A=A.substring(0,y),document.write(A+"...")}var _="",$=0;document.write('<br><div class="recent-posts-details">'),1==posts_date&&(_=_+w[parseInt(g,10)]+" "+v+" "+f,$=1),1==readmorelink&&(1==$&&(_+=" | "),_=_+'<a href="'+r+'" class="url" target ="_top">Read more</a>',$=1),1==showcommentslink&&(1==$&&(_+=" <br> "),"1 Comments"==l&&(l="1 Comment"),"0 Comments"==l&&(l="No Comments"),l='<a href="'+m+'" target ="_top">'+l+"</a>",_+=l,$=1),document.write(_),document.write("</div>"),document.write("</li>")}document.write("</ul>")}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var posts_no = 5;
var showpoststhumbs = true;
var readmorelink = true;
var showcommentslink = true;
var posts_date = true;
var post_summary = true;
var summary_chars = 40;</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showlatestpostswiththumbs"></script>
<a style="font-size: 9px; color: #CECECE; margin-top: 10px;" href="http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2014/11/5-cool-recent-post-widgets-for-blogger.html" rel="nofollow"></a>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<style type="text/css">
img.recent-post-thumb{padding:2px;width:65px;height:65px;float:left;margin:0px 10px 10px;border: 1px solid #69B7E2;}
.recent-posts-container {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
ul.recent-posts-container li{list-style-type: none; margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:12px;float:left;width:100%}
ul.recent-posts-container {counter-reset: countposts;list-style-type:none;padding:0;}
ul.recent-posts-container li:before {content: counter(countposts,decimal);counter-increment: countposts;z-index: 1;position:absolute; left: 0px; font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;background: #69B7E2;line-height:25px;height:25px;width:25px;text-align:center;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 50%;}
.recent-posts-container a{text-decoration:none;}
.recent-post-title {margin-bottom:5px;}
.recent-post-title a {font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #2aace3;}
.recent-posts-details {margin: 5px 0px 0px 92px;font-size:11px;}
.recent-posts-details a{color: #777;}
</style>
```

Comment: you say: "when I added the sidebar menu, it came up a problem" What is the exact problem???? - your link is redirected to error page

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float:left;` from those li

```
ul.recent-posts-container li {
     list-style-type: none; 
     margin-bottom: 10px; 
     font-size: 12px; 
    /* float: left; */ //REMOVED
     width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much ! I will teste it now

Comment: I ve removed /* float: left; */ //REMOVED but infortuantyll it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What is exactly the issue, i can't seem to see any other one